In a ring where $a+(1−ab)x$ is a unit, find some $y$ such that $b+y(1-ab)$ is a unit
If $a,b,x$
in any ring, such that $a+(1−ab)x$
is a unit. Prove that there is a $y$
in this ring such that $b+y(1−ab)$
is a unit.
I am trying to find $r_1
, r_2
, r_3$
in the ring that $r_1(b+r_2(1−ab))r_3$
is equal to $a+(1−ab)x$
, so I can prove that there is an ideal $(b+r_2(1−ab))=R$

(I did not downvote) A hint from Lam's A First Course in Noncommutative Rings, Exercise 1.25 ($c = 1-ab$): Set $u = a + cx \in U(R)$, and check that the element $y = (1 - bx)u^{-1}$ works. For this choice of $y$, an inverse for $b + yc$ is given by $a + x(1 - ba)$. The calculations are tricky, and have to be carried out carefully.

I solved the problem, thanks for the tip.Without this hint, how can I solve it on my own?Because I feel like I can't think of the solution?

See also this famous problem of Halmos. $\ \ $

I'm afraid I'm not sure how... This proof apparently first appears in Goodearl, Cancellation of low-rank vector bundles (1984), Lemma 3.1.

$\left(b+yc\right)\left(a+x\left(1-ba\right)\right)\\
=ba+bx(1-ba)+yca+ycx(1-ba)\\
=ba+bx-bxba+u^{-1}(a+x-abx)-bxu^{-1}(a+x-abx)-u^{-1}(a+x-abx)ba+bxu^{-1}(a+x-abx)ba\\
=ba+bx-bxba+1-bx-ba+bxba\\
=1$

Please copy-paste Lam's definitions of $c,u,y$ (provided by @Amateur_Algebraist's comment above) in your self-answer.
